# Set property method in grails could not change the instance globally

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class `DbUserSchemaServer` with a transient property `unassign`

```
class DbUserSchemaServer {
    static transients = ["unassign"]

    DbUser user
    String schema
    DbServer server
    BigInteger objects
    Date creationDate
    String schemaStatus //for dropping
    Boolean protect

    //Transients
    Boolean unassign

    static constraints = {
        user unique:false, nullable: false, blank:false
        schema unique:'server', nullable: false, blank:false
        server unique: false, nullable: false, blank:false
        objects blank:false, nullable:false
        creationDate blank:false, nullable:false
        schemaStatus nullable:true, blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        protect defaultValue: false
        unassign defaultValue: false
    }
}
```

In a service, I tried to change the value of `protect` property of a `DbUserSchemaServer` instance. The method as folows

```
public Boolean protectSchema(DbUserSchemaServer usrSchSrvInst) {
    println "protectSchema: "+usrSchSrvInst.schema
    if(!usrSchSrvInst.protect) { // If unprotected
        if(usrSchSrvInst.schemaStatus.equals("drop")) // If schema status is drop
            usrSchSrvInst.setSchemaStatus(null)
        usrSchSrvInst.setProtect(true)
        println "-->"+usrSchSrvInst.getProtect()
        return true
    }
    else {  // If already protected
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

When I tried to change the status of a schema *TEST_SCHEMA_1* by `setProtect(true)` call, it changes in the local view (prints true on std `println`), but doesn't change in the  database entry. I tried to save the instance by `instance.save()` bu no change in the behavior.

I am using grails 2.4.4 now. Previously, I used version 2.2.4 and it worked as expected. I have this issue when I migrated the application to version 2.4.4. What could be the reason, and how could it be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At what point in your service are you checking the state of the instance in the database?  When is your instance created?  Your method sets the protect variable but doesn't save the instance.

If you call `save()` then the instance isn't actually saved to the db, it's only saved to the DB when the session is flushed.  Try using:

```
save(flush: true, failOnError: false)
```

Comment: Initially I tried using save `(failOnError: true)`. No validation exceptions raised. I didn't understand the documentation for `flush` option. But it worked anyway.

Comment: OK - `flush()` just means to force the write to the database.  If you don't specify this, your update will get written to the DB, but not necessarily immediately.  Really good explanation here: http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/  Also look at Part 2 and 3 of the blog series too.